# Invalid namespace ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, ecmascript-5

when generated new app for extJs using this command on Ubuntu terminal `sencha generate app -ext MyApp path/to/folder`

that time terminal show me `Sencha Cmd v7.5.1.20 [ERR] The specified string cannot be converted into a valid namespace identifier [ERR] Invalid namespace : MyApp`

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but did you just run `sencha generate app -ext MyApp path/to/folder`? if you don't have an actual folder structure of `path/to/folder`, it might have errored. Maybe try `sencha generate app -ext MyApp .`, assuming you want the folder path to be your current working directory

Comment: try this `sencha generate app -ext MyApp .` but same issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue with my Arch environment: I couldn't install sencha-cmd through pacman or yay because running the installer would prompt a Java error complaining that the SecurityManager would be deprecated. I changed from openJDK 20 to 8 (in my case through the `archlinux-java` command) and that instantly fixed the error (and then allowed me to install sencha-cmd through pacman).

I ran into a weird bug afterwards where the workspace I was trying to clone wasn't recognizing the local packages, but it fixed Sencha Cmd from complaining about the "invalid namespace".